# Load H5PY File in Batches

Tags: python, h5py

I have created 200 H5PY Files as training data for a Neural-Network. The problem is that the loaded Files are at the limit of what my memory can handle. I would like to split each training file into to two batches.Let's say one batch has 69000 entries, I would like to have only 34500 in my memory, train the network, delete those entries from my memory and load the other half which could look like this:

```
for n in range(1,100):
   inputdata=h5py.File("Data/IN"+str(n), "r").get("Tree")[()].astype(np.float16)
   outputdata=h5py.File("Data/OUT"+str(n), "r").get("Tree")[()].astype(np.float16)

   phi.fit(inputdata, outputdata,epochs=2,batch_size=32)

   phi.save("trainedmodel_weights")
   del inputdata
   del outputdata
```

Is there a function integrated in h5py, that allows me this functionality and that I can loop over so that the .fit() function can be called?

Comment: The short answer is "I think you can do this". The devil is in the details. As I understand, you have 200 files: `Data/IN###` and `Data/OUT###` (where ### is 1-100), and each file has 1 dataset named "Tree" that you read into a NumPy array. Your psuedo code reads and fits on each IN## & OUT### loop (100 fit loops).If you want to use half of the data you will have to read files 1-50 into a single array, do the fit, then repeat for 51-100. Your bigger problem: when you fit the second loop, you need to read the weights from the first loop, then modify with the new training data.

Comment: as far as I know the weights after a fit are kept in the model if I dont compile the model again. So the for loop should be sufficient if I havent been falling for a misunderstanding.

Comment: OK, so you need to combine data from each ['Tree'] dataset in IN### and OUT### into a single array for  training. I assume they have consistent shape (same # of dimensions, but may have different sizes). What are the shapes, and how do you want to "stack" the  data. For example if each dataset is (100,100), we could create an array of shape (100,100,50) for 50 files. Please advise and I can provide some psuedo code as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved my issue by modifying my code like follows:

```
for n in range(1,10):
  for i in range(1):  # added
    inputdata=h5py.File("Data/IN"+str(n), "r").get("Tree")[()]
    **inputdata=np.array_split(inputdata, 2,axis=0)[i]**
    inputdata=inputdata.astype(np.float32)
    outputdata=h5py.File("Data/OUT"+str(n), "r").get("Tree")[()]
    **outputdata=np.array_split(outputdata, 2,axis=0)[i]**
    outputdata=outputdata.astype(np.float32)
    phi.fit(inputdata, outputdata,epochs=2,batch_size=32)
    phi.save("trainedmodel_weights")
    del inputdata
    del outputdata
```